# Post Request to Wicket

Tags: wicket

With **Wicket**,

How can I send the var **`slideCounter`** to Wicket?

Can someone provide an example?

I am unable find more information on this.

```
  $(document).on('click', '.lean-overlay', function() {
    var slideCounter = 0;

    // TODO Send slidecounter to wicket
});
```

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Calling+Wicket+from+Javascript https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/advanced.html#advanced_2

Comment: This doesnt help me, i read this several times already.  I am asking for "wicket.ajax.post" or something.In this documentation there is only 
var wcall = Wicket.Ajax.get({ u: '${callbackUrl}' + '${args}' });Still thanks for your reply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the possibility to call wicket code from javascript using ajax call backs. You can do something like this:

JAVA CODE:

```
AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior behave = new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior() {

        @Override
        public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
            super.renderHead(component, response);
            String componentMarkupId = component.getMarkupId();
            String callbackUrl = getCallbackUrl().toString();
            response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript(
                    "var componentMarkupId='" + componentMarkupId
                            + "'; var callbackUrl='" + callbackUrl + "';",
                    "values"));
        }

        protected void respond(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            IRequestParameters parameters = RequestCycle.get().getRequest()
                    .getQueryParameters();

            // write yout java code here
            // if you want to use the slideCounter variable
            // you have to retrieve its value like this:
            // parameters.getParameterValue("slideCounter").toString()

        }

    };

    add(behave);
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
$(document).on('click', '.lean-overlay', function() {
var slideCounter = 0;
executeJava(slideCounter);
});

    function executeJava(slideCounter) {
        try {
            var commandToSend = 'slideCounter=' + slideCounter;
            var wcall = Wicket.Ajax.post({
                u: callbackUrl + '&' + commandToSend
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Sending the request is as simple as: `Wicket.Ajax.post({"u": "the/url?slideCounter="+slideCounter})`

The more complex part is to construct `the/url`.

1. To send it to a Component this Component should implement IRequestListener interface. To construct the url use: `requestCycle.urlFor(component)`
2. To send it to a Behavior better instantiate AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior and use its `#getCallbackUrl()`

Once you have the url you need to store it in the page DOM, e.g. with OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("window.TheUrl='"+theUrl+"';")

Comment: ok i tried this, but like you said the problem is the url :( could you explain how i use the getCallbackUrl ?